# Always Receiving 400 Bad Response in Linux cURL Request

Tags: linux, curl, postman

I am hitting RabbitMQ remote server and trying to fetch the channels, using the below curl call:

> curl -i -X GET https://192.168.180.23:15671/api/channels -H 'accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' -H 'authorization: Basic cGhpYWRtaW46MW5mME1AdDFjc1BoIWx0MHI=' -H 'connection: keep-alive' -H 'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1' -k

But getting 400 Bad Request Response

> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
>   server: Cowboy
>   date: Sun, 11 Mar 2018 05:00:21 GMT
>   content-length: 0
>   vary: origin

But getting 200 Response when I am making same call using Postman.

Comment: Where did you get the Curl request from - Is this the same output code sample as Postman gives you? Have you tried a more simplistic query? Rabbit will give you an output with a lot less headers involved. https://cdn.rawgit.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/v3.7.4/priv/www/api/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, I found the answer, a **;** was causing the problem.
So, it should be

```
-H 'accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*'
```

Instead of `-H 'accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;'`